# MySQL HTML Output Embed Hyperlink

Tags: html, mysql, bash, hyperlink

Currently I have a bash shell script that executes a mysql query using the -H option to generate HTML.  The output is redirected to a file which is then emailed.

Is there a way to embed a hyperlink into one of the columns of a query that generates HTML output?

For example, if I run the following I get a HTML table of id's.

mysql -H -t -e "select id from users" testdb

But what I'd like is a table of id's where the id is a hyperlink.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand your last sentence.

Comment: I think CycleGeek wants to replace the id field by an hyperlink. But how are these hyperlinks made ? Why not use simple PHP script  for doing that ?

Comment: Because CycleGeek doesn't know php.  :)

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi: thank you. CycleGeek: post output of your mysql command.

Comment: <table border=1><tr><th>ID</th></tr><tr><td>123</td></tr><tr><td>456</td></tr><tr><td>789</td></tr></table>

Answer (score 0):

Pipe results to sed and use substitution to create a link.

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4

Comment: That would work in the simple example I gave, however I really need to do this in the fourth column of a table where the columns before it vary in content and length.